# Finding X such that XA=B where A and B are non squared

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have two matrices $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&2\\3&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}-5&-1&0\\6&-3&7\end{bmatrix}$. Under normal $XA=B$ circumstances, where $A$ is square I could just simply do a $X=BA^{-1}$ but how would I go about find $X$ since $A$ can't be inverted in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postmultiply by $A^\top$ to get,
$$XAA^\top = BA^\top$$
Now, note that $AA^\top$ is an invertible square matrix and do what you wanted to do.
$$\implies X = BA^\top(AA^\top)^{-1}$$

Comment: Caution: that $X$ would indeed be the only possible solution, but you don't know that it **is** a solution until you check $XA = B$.  For example, if you changed the $7$ in $B$ to something else, it would not work

Comment: Yeah, @Robert, I know that. Actually we are using sort of a Moore Penrose inverse of $A$. It is also the solution minimising the norm of $B-XA$, the kind of thing we do in multiple linear regression.